# Corrupt or blank file when downloaded from Sharepoint using rest API ajax call javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, ajax, file-download

I am trying to download a file from Sharepoing using ajax call from html page. I am able to upload successfully but when I try to download a file, in case of text file, the download is successfull and file opens with correct content, but in case of pdf, the file is downloaded as blank and in case of ppt, the file is corrput.

I am using below code. For now, I am hardcoding everything to get a successfull file. Please let me know what i may be missing.

```
<apex:page controller="XXX_SharePoint" showHeader="false" sidebar="false"  showChat="false" docType="html-5.0" standardStylesheets="false" action="{!onPageLoad}">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <Script>


        window.onload = () => {
            let code = '{!ACCESS_TOKEN}';   
            let extension = '{!extension}';

            //make a ajax callout
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://m.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/XXXDocument/pdf4.pdf')/$value", 
                type: 'get',  
                contentType: true, 
                processData: false, 
                headers: { accept: 'application/json',
                          "Authorization": "Bearer "+code,
                         },
                success: function(response){
                    alert('success response'+response)
                    var a = document.createElement('a');
                    var binaryData = [];
                    binaryData.push(response);
                    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData),{type: "application/octet-stream"});
                    //var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.blob);
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = 'myfile.pdf';//+extension;
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                    a.remove();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                },
            });
        }
    </Script>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi, try adding  binaryStringResponseBody: true in your ajax call.

Comment: I still got the blank pdf. this is how i added - `type: 'get',  
    contentType: true, 
    processData: false,
        binaryStringResponseBody:true,`

Comment: Hi, did you get the file content fine? Problem is when downloading it as a new file, correct? Is opening the URL of the file through SharePoint's download.aspx in a new window an option, like https://<SiteUrl>/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceUrl=https://<SiteUrl>/DocLibrary/Test.docx

Comment: I am getting the file content but not in readable format. When i download the text file.. it downloads as well as shows the content as well inside it. So I believe the response is correct. All i am missing here is how to parse that response back to pdf

Comment: Hi, did you try changing the content type to 'application/pdf' already? Looks like you just need to find the proper content type setting for your file.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. yes I tried with application/pdf also . Still no luck

`var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData),{type: "application/pdf"});`

Comment: Last suggestion, response might already be an array buffer, did you try to put it directly in Blob? like,  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(response)...
And check how you declare Blob, I think the type should be included in the constructor. var blob = new Blob(response, {type: 'application/pdf'});

var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

Comment: I tried this.. But still no luck :( `var blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); `

Comment: Is there any way to find the response type so that we can parse the same?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107306/discussion-between-ubk-and-samir).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we have seen in this problem, mentioning `responseType :'arraybuffer'` or `responseType :'blob'`, or using `'binaryStringResponseBody:true'` didn't help.

In all cases we were getting the response but it was not recognized as our intended content type, i.e. PDF. In console it looked like below:

[image]

To fix this we have to force the stream to be treated and parsed as 'text/plain', and it worked beautifully!!

```
window.onload = () => {
        let code = '{!ACCESS_TOKEN}';   

        //make a ajax callout
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://<YourSharePointSite>.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/CEPDocument/pdf4.pdf')/$value", 
            type: 'get',  
            contentType: true, 
            processData: false,
            encoding: null,
            headers: { 
                accept: 'application/json',
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + code
                },
            beforeSend: function (request) {
                request.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
            },
            success: function(response){
                var binary = "";
                var responseTextLen = response.length;

                for ( i = 0; i < responseTextLen; i++ ) {
                    binary += String.fromCharCode(response.charCodeAt(i) & 255)
                }

                var a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = "data:application/pdf;base64," + btoa(binary);
                a.download = 'myfile.pdf';
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                a.remove();
            },
        });
    }
```

Here is a different implementation of the 'success' method:

```
success: function(response){                
                var i = 0,
                dataArray = new Uint8Array(response.length);
                for (; i < response.length; i++) {
                    dataArray[i] = response.charCodeAt(i)
                }

                var blob = new Blob([dataArray.buffer], {
                    type: "application/pdf"
                });
                let link = document.createElement('a');
                link.download = 'ubkfile.pdf';

                let reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(blob); // converts the blob to base64 and calls onload

                reader.onload = function() {
                  link.href = reader.result;
                  link.click();
                };
            }
```

Change the content type to "image/png" if you are loading PNG images.

Please mark as answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for PDF. Will check  for excel and ppt file.

Comment: I have checked for PDF and PNG. It should work for other file types as well. Just set the file type (MIME type) properly. Check this post for Microsoft Office MIME typeshttps://stackoverflow.com/a/4212908/4489918

Comment: I can't express how grateful I am. I was going mad. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually,  I have discovered that it is really easy to override the underlying `XMLHttpRequest` that powers the `$.ajax()` call in order to get an `ArrayBuffer` response.  (See my answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60570706/988264).)

What you do is basically something like this:

```
window.onload = () => {
    let code = '{!ACCESS_TOKEN}';   
    let extension = '{!extension}';

    // make XMLHttpRequest override
    var xhrOverride = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // tell it you want an ArrayBuffer
    xhrOverride.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

    //make a ajax callout
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://m.sharepoint.com/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/XXXDocument/pdf4.pdf')/$value", 
        type: 'GET',  
        contentType: true, 
        processData: false, 
        headers: {
            accept: 'application/json',
            "Authorization": "Bearer "+code,
        },
        xhr: function() { return xhrOverride; },
        success: function(response){

            // "response" is now a proper ArrayBuffer
            // which you can use to make your Blob!

            alert('success response'+response)
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            var binaryData = [];
            binaryData.push(response);
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData),{type: "application/octet-stream"});
            //var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(response.blob);
            a.href = url;
            a.download = 'myfile.pdf';//+extension;
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.click();
            a.remove();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        },
    });
}
```